# How disabled days outside month in react-datepicker?

Tags: react-datepicker

I want days outside of the month to be non-clickable.
Please, tell me how to implement it?

There was an idea to do visibility: hidden, but it doesn't suit me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css to override default styling of the outside days of the month

```
.react-datepicker__day--outside-month {
  color: #ccc !important; /* to add disabled feeling */
  pointer-events: none; /* to prevent click */
}
```